# Implementing an arithmetic parser in Prolog

Tags: prolog, context-free-grammar, dcg, arithmetic-expressions

I have the following Prolog code:

```
expression-->first,operator,second.
first-->[X].
operator-->['+'];['-'].
second-->[X].
```

After compilation, the machine responds with "yes" in the command line for the following types of queries:

```
| ?- expression([5,'+',3],[]).
| ?- expression(['a','-','b'],[]).
| ?- expression([2.8,'+',3.2],[]).
```

How do I limit this to numbers only? Therefore, only expressions involving numbers should be truthful, like this one: `| ?- expression([92,'+',23.48],[]).`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether `X` in `first` and `second` are numbers:

```
first-->[X], {number(X)}.

second-->[X], {number(X)}.
```